# Kipling’s Aerial Board of Control stories

Tags: short-stories

It turns out that science fiction was invented by a Nobel laureate in 1905... (sure, sure, there are earlier examples, but how cool is this version?)

It is relatively easy to find Rudyard Kipling’s most famous short story collections. But I have not been able to get a book that contains the Aerial Board of Control stories. Is there any available compilation that includes "With the Night Mail" (1905) and "As Easy as ABC" (1912)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Needless to say, ["With the Night Mail"](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/29135) and ["As Easy as A.B.C."](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/13085) are in the public domain, and available as Project Gutenberg etexts; I assume you are looking for real books.

Did you try the [ISFDB](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/index.cgi)?

Here is the ISFDB bibliography for [Rudyard Kipling](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?1961).

Here is the ISFDB bibliography for ["With the Night Mail"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?68044).

Here is the ISFDB bibliography for ["As Easy as A.B.C."](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?68361)

The ISFDB lists several compilations containing both of those stories:
[*A Separate Star: A Science Fiction Tribute to Rudyard Kipling*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?1109), David Drake, Sandra Miesel eds.
[*John Brunner Presents Kipling's Science Fiction*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?29247), John Brunner ed.
[*Rudyard Kipling's Tales of Horror and Fantasy*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?295851), with introduction by Neil Gaiman
[*With the Night Mail and As Easy as A.B.C.*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?385917), HiLo Books